# Is there a way to set the correct text of a page for every element in a list?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am kind of new to android studio, I have an array of strings for my list and when i click on an item from that list it takes me to the correct page. However, there are 100 items on the list and it's not logical to create 100 java files for all of them to set the text on that page. 
My question is: is there a way to set the text to the correct item of list just after or before clicking that item?

Comment: I don't know how it works (and you should follow the instructions on making questions) but you can just have an intermediate function or simply pass the id of whatever you're fetching and when displaying the other page just fetch by post_id or something.

That way you can have 1 template and n number of content to display.

Comment: What do you mean with `the correct text of a page`? You mean the title of an activity?

Comment: @AlexMamo so basically, i have a page which contains a list and when i click an item in this list it should send me to another page and modify the textView that corresponds to the selected item of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have in your `FirstActivity` a `ListView` please use the following code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("item", item);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

To get the item in your `SecondActivity` please use this code:

```
String item = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("item");
yourTextView.setText(item);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps a lot since now i dont need to put if(position == 0) and so on to do something, so thank you a lot for that. However, I am try to set the text to a string that i have stored in a file called content.xml and the only way i know to get that is by: getResources().getString(R.string.NameofMyString) and each item in the list has a different string.

Comment: Happy to hear that. In order to answer to the second question, you need to post another question, so me and other users can help you. The second question is not related with the first one.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you, consider accepting it. Thanks!